# How to send the raw-data with GET request in jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, curl

Now, there is new API and I got just a url and some parameters. If I send the param like this

https://api.somthing.com/Search?zip=$zip&id=$id&key=$key

then this doesn't work. But if I send in POSTMAN data as raw-data, then it's working. GET requests are not expected to have bodies. But I have implemented the same in PHP using cURL and created custom GET request with raw-data. I don't know how to implement the same in jQuery AJAX. Please help.

I've tried something like this:

```
var settings = {
  "url": url,
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": "__cd=d311a6f2055dd5fb9462c000a297f4a0158451265"
  },
  "data": jsonData,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Quentin's answer is correct, however I would raise this issue with whoever created the API, as this is a mistake on their part which needs to be corrected

Comment: Hi, 
actually I've resolved this issue in PHP using cURL. So I thought this is somehow possible in jQuery as well.

Answer (score 3):

> GET requests are not expected to have bodies.

This is true. The behaviour of a GET request with a body is explicitly undefined in the HTTP specification.

The [next version of the specification](https://httpwg.org/http-core/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics-latest.html#rfc.section.9.3.1.p.6) has stronger language:

> A client SHOULD NOT generate content in a GET request unless it is made directly to an origin server that has previously indicated, in or out of band, that such a request has a purpose and will be adequately supported. An origin server SHOULD NOT rely on private agreements to receive content, since participants in HTTP communication are often unaware of intermediaries along the request chain.

XMLHttpRequest (the underlying API used by jQuery Ajax) does not support the sending of a request body with a GET request (not does XHR's successor — `fetch`).

The browser, as a "participant in HTTP communication", doesn't know about your agreement with the server to sent GET with a body and doesn't support it.

The only way to do this would be to proxy the request through your server.